# Scala type mismatch when it shouldn't?

Tags: scala, recursion

I have these two functions in scala:

```
def recursive_func(x: Position, count: Int) : Int = {
      if(getNewPositions(x).isEmpty){
        count + 1;
      } else {
        for(n <- getNewPositions(x)){
          recursive_func(n, count+1);
        }
      }
}

def getNewPositions(x: Position) : List[Position] = {
    val possible : List[Position] = List((x._1 + 5,x._2 + 6), (x._1 + 6,x._2 + 7), (x._1 + 7,x._2 + 8), (x._1 + 8, x._2 + 9));
    val answer : List[Position] = for (n <- possible if canMakeMove(n)) yield n;
    answer;
}
```

The second returns a List of positions which is sometimes empty. The first is a recursive function that should return 1 if the list returned by getNewPositions is empty, or iterate over it if the list is not. However I'm getting this error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
```

which I presume is because the compiler is trying to do for(n <- getNewPositions(x)) on an empty list even though in my head it shouldnt because of the if statement it's wrapped in? I know for sure that the getNewPositions function works fine and returns the appropriate list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your method is returning void while expected is integer.

Comment: I realise, but I'm not sure why?

Comment: I guess you are missing a return statement ? return answer ?

Comment: No, thats not needed in Scala. The getNewPositions method works fine.

Comment: can you explain your getNewPosition function?

Comment: Get rid of the semi-colons, you don't need them in Scala.

Comment: answer dataType is List[Pos] but getNewPositions function is returning List[Position]. is it a mistake?

Comment: Sorry mistyped it on stackoverflow, should be List[Position]

Comment: and the getNewPosition, takes a Position which is a basically a coordinate (x, y) and changes the values of x and y, and then returns all the ones that are possible by checking with the method canMakeMove.

Comment: when you do `for(n <- getNewPositions(x))` here `n` becomes `List[Position]` not `Position` . so you can't pass `n` which is `List[Position]` to `recursive_func` which requires `Position`. Are you getting the point.?

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I thought that n would take the value of each position inside the list. How would I go about getting each position instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors in your code:

1. First:

   `for(n <- getNewPositions(x)){
         recursive_func(n, count+1);
       }`

   Type of this expression is unit (this is causing your compilation error). Reason: `for (n <- coll) {..}` expands to `coll.foreach(n => {..})`
2. Second: `for (n <- possible canMakeMove(n)) yield {}` is definitly not a valid scala syntax

Comment: Sorry for the second part I mistyped the if statement on here so it should be  for (n <- possible if canMakeMove(n)) yield n;

For the first part, I think coll.foreach(n => {..}) is the functionality I'm looking for, but why would it return unit if the list isn't empty?

Comment: Method can't easily change it's returning type based on input (unless input carries some type information). What's more `foreach` has the following signature: `foreach(T => Unit]): Unit`, You can add `yield` keyword to use `map` instead of `foreach`

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, I don't think it's possible to call that function recursively using Yield seeing as one returns an Int and the other is a List. How would you go about this?